# Pass value from run-script in Xcode to compilation

Tags: c++, ios, c, xcode, macos

Is it possible to define a new environment variable in X code, and pass it as a flag when compiling source C/C++ file in Xcode ?

I've tried to add "Run script" phase prior to "Compile Sources" in my project "Build Phases"

Here's the script I run, where I get the value of 'X':

[image]

And in "Compile Sources" I've added 'X' to "Other C Flags"

[image]

But unfortunately, X is undefined in this scope, so X_FOR_APP is empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried  `export x`

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot find any way to define a global environment variable In Xcode that will be accessible to all build phases.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I haven't found exactly what I was needed, but here's a nice workaround.

Instead of passing macro definitions via the compilation command , it's possible to create an output header file from the preceding "run script" phase with all the necessary definitions which will be inserted to this header from the script.

This "tells" the next build phases (compile sources) that the file can be included although it's not yet existing.

During compilation, we first conduct "run script" and the file is created under `$(DERIVED_FILE_DIR)/myheader.h`, ready to be included while running the compilation itself on the source file.

[image]